# In-place replacement of a pattern in a string

Tags: string, algorithm, string-algorithm

In an interview I was asked a question on strings.
The problem is given a string **s1= "ABCDBCCDABCD"**. and a **pattern "BC"**. we have to replace this pattern with other string ("UVW" or "U"or "uv").
This need to be down in-place.

```
    Take the case as:  
          replace "BC" with  following 
 a) "uvw"   s1=AUVWDUVWCDAUVWD .
 b)  "U"    s1=AUDUCDAUD .
 c)  "UV"   s1=AUVDUVCDAUVD .
```

It will be helpful you someone provide a program along with algorithm.

Comment: You can't do that "in-place" if the pattern you're substituting is longer than the original pattern. (Unless your string is a linked list of chars rather than a contiguous array?)

Comment: This is not possible in the general case since it may require extending the string.

Comment: Yes that is the challenge .. in-case of c/Cpp use realloc/remalloc.

Comment: Well, that's NOT in-place for any reasonable definition of the word.

Comment: Why its please explain .... by using remalloc/reallac I am doing it in-place. U are allowed to do that.. But the question was asked in the above form.... come up with a algo..

Comment: Well if you're reallocating memory it's hardly in place. At that point you might as well whack everything into an expandable data structure like a linked list as @us2012 suggests.

Comment: Ok.. I agree... remove in-line... what will be the best solution you will give.

Comment: There's a big difference between "in-place" and "in-line". Was the original question to do it "in-line"? That would at least make sense. (Inline means that you read the input without being able to rewind; usually, you only have a constant amount of buffer space.)

Answer (score 0):

My plan would be to create a linked list that will hold the final output.

Create a variable to hold the current index the in the pattern.

Loop over the input string, if the current character matches the character at the index in the pattern then we increment the index.

If the index is now equal to the length of the pattern then append the replace string to the output and reset the index

If the current character does not match the character at the index in the pattern then append eveything from the pattern up to (and including) the index in the pattern and reset the index.

In java this looks something like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s = "ABCDBCCDABCD";
    System.out.println(replaceAll(s, "BC", "UVW"));
    System.out.println(replaceAll(s, "BC", "U"));
    System.out.println(replaceAll(s, "BC", "UV"));
}

public static String replaceAll(final String in, final String p, final String r) {
    final List<Character> newString = new LinkedList<>();

    final List<Character> pattern = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Character c : p.toCharArray()) {
        pattern.add(c);
    }
    final List<Character> replace = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Character c : r.toCharArray()) {
        replace.add(c);
    }
    int positionInPattern = 0;
    for (final char c : in.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == pattern.get(positionInPattern)) {
            positionInPattern++;
            if (positionInPattern == pattern.size()) {
                newString.addAll(replace);
                positionInPattern = 0;
            }
        } else {
            if (positionInPattern > 0) {
                newString.addAll(pattern.subList(0, positionInPattern + 1));
                positionInPattern = 0;
            }
            newString.add(c);
        }
    }
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (final Character c : newString) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Output:

```
AUVWDUVWCDAUVWD
AUDUCDAUD
AUVDUVCDAUVD
```

Comment: I think this is not an inplace substitution because the returned string is a completely different buffer than the input...

Answer (score 0):

You actually can do this in-place, in languages that have realloc (if the realloc succeeds in-place, which is not at all guaranteed).

If the replacement string is longer than the original pattern, then we first scan for the pattern and calculate the length of the new string. Then we call realloc to extend the available buffer and start copying to string backwards.

```
[A][B][C][D][B][C][C][D][A][B][C][D][␀]
# extend buffer:
[A][B][C][D][B][C][C][D][A][B][C][D][␀][ ][ ][ ]
# after first few iterations of the copy loop
[A][B][C][D][B][C][C][D][A][B][C][D][␀][ ][ ][␀]
[A][B][C][D][B][C][C][D][A][B][C][D][␀][ ][D][␀]
[A][B][C][D][B][C][C][D][A][B][C][D][␀][C][D][␀]
[A][B][C][D][B][C][C][D][A][B][C][U][V][W][D][␀]
[A][B][C][D][B][C][C][D][A][B][A][U][V][W][D][␀]
```

My C is a little rusty, but this code seems to do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int pat_match(char* str, char* pattern)
{
    while(*pattern == *str) 
    {
        if(*pattern == '\0' || *str == '\0') break;
        pattern++;
        str++;
    }
    return (*pattern == '\0');
}

char* replace(char* str, char* pattern, char* rep)
{
    int len_str = strlen(str);
    int len_pattern = strlen(pattern);
    int len_rep = strlen(rep);

    if(len_rep > len_pattern)
    {
        int count_matches = 0;
        char* scan = str;
        while(*scan) 
        {
            if(pat_match(scan, pattern))
            {
                printf("Match!\n");
                count_matches++;
                scan += len_pattern;
            }
            else
            {
                scan++;
            }
        }
        if(count_matches == 0) return str;

        int len_new = len_str + count_matches * (len_rep - len_pattern);

        str = realloc(str, len_new+1);
        int new_pos, pos;
        for(pos=len_str-1,new_pos=len_new-1;pos>=0;pos--,new_pos--)
        {
            if(pat_match(str+pos, pattern))
            {
                memcpy(str+new_pos-(len_rep-len_pattern), rep, len_rep);
                new_pos = new_pos - (len_rep-len_pattern);
            }
            else
            {
                str[new_pos] = str[pos];
            }
        }
        str[len_new] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        int new_pos, pos;
        for(pos=0,new_pos=0; pos<len_str; pos++,new_pos++)
        {
            if(pat_match(str+pos, pattern))
            {
                memcpy(str+new_pos, rep, len_rep);
                pos += len_pattern-1;
                new_pos += len_rep-1;
            }
            else
            {
                str[new_pos] = str[pos];
            }
        }
        str[new_pos] = '\0';
    }

    return str;
}

void main() 
{
    char* s = (char*)malloc(12);
    strcpy(s, "Hello world");
    printf("%s\n", replace(s, "llo", "x"));
}
```